# Reduce multiple ORs in IF statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a simpler way to rewrite the following condition in JavaScript?

```
if ((x == 1) || (x == 3) || (x == 4) || (x == 17) || (x == 80)) {...}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use an array of valid values and test it with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if ([1, 3, 4, 17, 80].indexOf(x) != -1)
```

---

**Edit**    Note that `indexOf` was just added in ECMAScript 5 and thus is not implemented in every browser. But you can use the [following code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) to add it if missing:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Or, if you’re already using a JavaScript framework, you can also use its implementation of that method.

Comment: +1... This is the neatest. The `in` operator does not work correctly for arrays, as you suggested: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/in_Operator

Comment: @sterofrog: You can add indexOf to older browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @Daniel: yes, this should be added to the answer, for gooogler's benefit

Comment: Bear in mind that setting Array prototype members breaks the for (i in array) construct, as those prototype members will show up as items of every array.  If Array prototype members are set (e.g. with this, by mootools, etc.), you have to iterate over the members with `for var i = 0; i < array.length; i++` , or use a framework function that handles it for you (e.g. jQuery.each()).

Comment: @Joey Adams: `for … in` is for object properties and not array keys. *Always* use a the standard ranging `for` loop for array iteration. (jQuery does that too.)

Answer (score 7):

```
switch (x) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 17:
    case 80:
        //code
        break;
    default:
        //code
}
```

Comment: not exactly simpler, but a nice alternative, and good use of not using a break, which btw you forgot to put after the code in `case 80:`

Comment: and you need the break in the default case

Comment: @BritishDeveloper the default clause doesn't require a break, as there cannot be any cases after the default. For example, see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: @cmptrgeekken true - i had my c# eyes in

Answer (score 3):

This is a little function I found somewhere on the web:

```
function oc(a) {
    var o = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        o[a[i]] = '';
    }
    return o;
}
```

Used like this:

```
if (x in oc(1, 3, 4, 17, 80)) {...}
```

I'm using it for strings myself; haven't tried with numbers, but I guess it would work.

Answer (score 2):

a regular expression test uses the string value of x:

```
if(/^[134]|17|80$/.test(x)){/*...*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your own example and get rid of a few characters, making it easier on the eyes..:

```
if (x == 1 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 17 || x == 80) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

many options

```
if ([0, 1, 3, 4, 17, 80].indexOf(x) > 0)

if(/^(1|3|4|17|80)$/.test(x))

if($.inArray(x, [1, 3, 4, 17, 80])
```

another one, based on [Ed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630364/reduce-multiple-ors-in-if-statement-in-javascript/2630827#2630827)

```
function list() {
    for (var i = 0, o = {}; i < arguments.length; i++)
        o[arguments[i]] = '';
    return o;
}


if(x in list(1, 3, 4, 17, 80))...
```

Comment: JavaScript’s array index starts with 0.

Comment: @stereofrog: Yes: `[0, 1, 3, 4, 17, 80].indexOf(0) === 0`.

Comment: @stereofrog: so, I think `if ([0, 1, 3, 4, 17, 80].indexOf(x) > 0)` needs to be `if ([0, 1, 3, 4, 17, 80].indexOf(x) >= 0)`

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo, this would return 'true' for x=0, which is wrong

Comment: @stereofrog: Ok, I see that you've added an extra element in the array. But why not `if ([1, 3, 4, 17, 80].indexOf(x) != -1)`?

Comment: @stereofrog: I promise I didn't downvote. But I still did not get why you prefer to add a fictitious first element.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the simplest way...

```
    if([1,3,4,17,80].includes(x)){
        console.log(true); 
        // rest of the code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@Santosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56637802/6904888) I created a simplified version:

```js
const input = x => [1, 3, 4, 17, 80].includes(x);

console.log(input(10));
console.log(input(1));
```