# Matching a value to JSON array values in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON array that looks like this:

```
['Monkey','Cheetah','Elephant','Lizard','Spider']
```

I also have a text input. I want to test whether the value of the input upon 'blur' is also in the array and if it is do something.

Knowing a bit of python I tried something like this:

```
var existing_animals = ['Monkey','Cheetah','Elephant','Lizard','Spider']
$('input').blur(function() {
  user_animal = $(this).val()
  if (user_animal in existing_animals) {
    alert('Animal already exists!')
  }
});
```

So, how rookie is my mistake?

Comment: Sorry about the typo in the heading and in the example - should say 'user_animal in existing_animals'

Comment: The code you posted checks for existing_animals.Monkey (or, equivalently, existing_animals['Monkey']). The array stores it like: existing_animals[0] = 'Monkey'; it's not associative. I think korchev's solution is the best one (using $.inArray), but you could also make it associative as Matt suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `in` operator checks if a key is present in a dictionary (object). It however does now work for arrays. The right approach is to use [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
if ($.inArray(user_animal, existing) > -1) {
    alert('Animal already exists!')
}
```

Comment: I knew I use jQuery for a reason, while the other answers may be right, this is simple enough even for me, thanks

Answer (score 4):

`in` is for checking if an **object** includes the attribute, where-as you're using an array.

If you want to use your `in`, you can do:

```
var existing_animals = {
  "Monkey":1,
  "Cheetah":1
};
```

etc, then all will be fine using `in`, however, it would be better to continue using your Array, and simply loop over it.

```
$('input').blur(function() {
  user_animal = $(this).val()

  for (var i=0;i<existing_animals.length;i++) {
     if (existing_animals[i] == user_animal) {
        alert("Animal exists");

        break;
     };
  };
});
```

The ECMA 5th edition introduces an `indexOf` method for Arrays, so it should be as easy as doing:

```
if (existing_animals.indexOf(user_animal) != -1) {
   alert("Animal exists");
};
```

However, IE doesn't support this; [you can implement it yourself though.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: I just used 'in' because it's a concept I use when writing python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the "in" keyword in JS, this might be helpful:
[Reduce multiple ORs in IF statement in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630364/reduce-multiple-ors-in-if-statement-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might find your answer in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array).

Since the JSON evaluates to an array, you should be looking at the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function. Not sure why you mentioned python here..